# What is the usage of the preposition "At" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The headline is:

"At Politico’s New Owner, Allegations of Sex, Lies and a Secret Payment

Axel Springer, a German media giant, seems stuck in the past when it comes to the workplace and deal-making, our columnist Ben Smith writes."

I can undestand if it is: "At Politicos" but not, "At Politico’s New Owner" At the Owner??????
what does that means?

Comment: Axel Springer seems to be the name of a company rather than a man, so it means 'within the company' or 'at their offices'.

Comment: @Kate: good enough for me, that should be an answer

Comment: It's a big help if you quote the headline correctly, and provide a link to it: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/17/business/media/axel-springer-bild-julian-reichelt.html

Comment: OP, please read up about prepositions in English, prepositions and their use are widely explained. If you want to get a thorough understanding, which will help you all your life, have a look at "English Prepositions Explained" the revised edition by Seth Lindstromberg

Comment: Also relevant: 1) Headlines are written in a condensed syntax, and seldom use grammatically complete structures. 2) As a result they can often be perplexing or unclear. IMO this is not a great one (though by far not the worst). Oh, and 3) @JavaLatte I've observed the nytimes often make edits to headlines after they've gone live, so there's a chance they tweaked it on the fly...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual title from the [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/17/business/media/axel-springer-bild-julian-reichelt.html).

> At Axel Springer, Politico’s New Owner, Allegations of Sex, Lies and a Secret Payment

Axel Springer is a company, and **at** indicates a place... in this case, a place of work.